# Azure cloud service deployment without node_modules

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm using azure cloud service with Web & Worker Role and Angular4. How can deploy package without node_modules and run NPM install command after complete deployment. Is there any way?

Comment: There is quite a bit of documentation around startup scripts with cloud services. I suggest you start there.

Comment: See [Windows Azure Startup task to run npm install to avoid deploying node modules](https://github.com/woloski/nodeonazure-blog/blob/master/articles/startup-task-to-run-npm-in-azure.markdown).